# How the kernel functions work?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

Normally during a function call the function gets pushed into the stack part of the process and the calling function waits. But the program stack requires a process right? But the kernel is not part of any process (by kernel I mean the part that does file management and interprocess communication ) . But I assume even the kernel uses some kinds of functions to get various things done. So how are those functions in the kernel organized if they don’t use a process.??

Comment: Yes it does use functions. You could read (part of) the source. (remeber it is open source!) Start in subdirectory mm.

Comment: I read that the kernel itself is not a process. I wanna know how the kernel can execute itself without being a process.

Comment: It does not execute itself, it is invoked by the bootstrap, and runs continously (if called by syscalls or interrupts) And it does not need a process number, because it is not a process. After initialisation, the kernel calls only one process: init (pid=1) All other processes are children or grandchildren of init.

Comment: You can think of the kernel as a giant shared library that interfaces your programs to hardware and handles process scheduling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You confusing things of a different sort. Basically stack is a region in memory and some hardware support (register to hold top of the stack - esp and register to hold current stack frame base ebp and push, pop, call, ret instructions. I mean x86). When you have established this esp and allocated memory for the stack - you are done, you can use it. So to use a stack you don't need to use a "process". Process is a conception of a different order. In other words nothing holds kernel from allocating a stack for itself ...

Answer (score 1):

Related, there's a nice summary of how a "syscall" is made (the mechanism by which non-kernel processes call "into" the kernel) on x86 Linux [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/khg/HyperNews/get/syscall/syscall86.html).  The short story is, the calling process generates an interrupt with an [0x80 INT instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_%28x86_instruction%29)... and then the kernel handles the interrupt (which is something kernels are quite good at, what with needing to deal with HW interrupts from peripherals and chipset and the like).  See the article for the gnarly details of how the kernel figures out who created the interrupt and what they wanted.